# Why is almost everyone who is not Italian a Jew?

Tags: casino, goodfellas

Watching movies made by Martin Scorsese, ***Casino*** and ***Goodfellas*** I can't help but notice that almost everyone of any significance that is not an Italian is a Jew or Jewish.

I mean even degrading comments involve Jews. Admittedly, I don't know much about Jewish people or the religion.

Here are just a few scenes as to what I am talking about.

Comment: Is this a question or a comment?  BTW, James Conway (from Scorsese's Goodfellas) was Irish.  Gangs Of New York also centered around the Irish.  Of course, you could also say Scorsese's more famous movies centered around organized crime, and the Italians and Jews were central to that.  Jews like Bugsy Siegel pretty much ran Vegas in its infancy.  Check out the [National Crime Syndicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Crime_Syndicate) for more connections.

Comment: @JohnnyBones, so was Ace Rothstein, that is my question why was someone either a Jew or Italian? And to answer your question, it has a question mark, so it is a question.

Comment: I am Italian-American that grew up in NE New Jersey and I literally didn't know what a protestant was until I moved to Va as a teenager. Everyone I knew was (or was assumed to be) Italian, Jewish, or Puerto Rican and thus either Catholic or Jewish.  I am sure this isn't totally accurate but it is sure the way it seemed. I will add that this was in the late '70s and early '80s. When Scorsese was a kid, the ethnic groups were even more insular.

Comment: @KennyPeanuts, that is exactly what I wanted to know. I have no idea what it was like in those days and in those areas.

Comment: @KyloRen yeah I think it is a fair question.  It never occurred to me because it is so consistent with my exp. but don't have an answer other than my personal experience, so I chose to comment and not answer.  (I wasn't the DV, just so you know).

Comment: I will second Kenny above - I grew up in Brooklyn and the ethnic/religious mix was very similar - all Catholics and Jews of various ethnic backgrounds but mostly Italian, Irish or Eastern European.

Comment: @JohnnyBones even though I don't think Scorsese saw to the day to day, that was more Tim Van Patten, Boardwalk Empire too had a lot of subtext with the Irish and Italians whether we're taking Nucky (his family), Margaret, The Darmodys (Clearly Jimmy was super important) or Luciano & Gyp Rosette (tech Cannavale is part cuben in real life, but the character hailed from Sicily if I remember right). And then you have one signifgant Jewish character with the fictional version of Arnold Ronstein.

Comment: I agree that in gangster films/tv series, which no doubt has some parallels to how some may have felt in real life, that we have characters that use Religion and ethnicity as a means to seek power and degrade others, but really it's just an excuse for their individualized brand of narcissism and a way to never have to look at themselves and their own hypcracy.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are wrong in your perception:

- Ace Rothstein is the only Jewish main character in *Casino*.
- Karen Hill is the only Jewish main character in *Goodfellas*.

I don't remember these movies having that much Jewish characters. Other non Italian-American main characters of these two movies are Irish descent, or simply undescribed American characters.

Now about insults and degrading comments, this is a common trope in gangster movies where each gangster community (Irish, Russian, Jewish, Italian, American etc...) insults other ones with racist prejudices.

Comment: I am not going to edit my question due to possible negative response to your answer, but I am trying to say that everything revolved around's Jewish and Italians. Why is this?

Comment: And what about the Jewish broad Nikky is trying to lay?

Comment: @KyloRen, In Godfellas Jimmy and Henry are Irish. I didn't count Nikky's broad as a main character.

Comment: @SilverBebs *technically* the question doesn't say anything about "main character"... it says "of any significance"... one could argue that means "anyone who's mentioned in the film".

Comment: @SilverBebs - Was Henry Irish?  I don't recall.  Because the real Henry Hill was Sicilian.  Maybe you've got him confused with Jimmy Conway?

Comment: @JohnnyBones, his Father was Irish and his Mother was Sicillian.

Comment: @JohnnyBones, this is one of the movie plots, I recall, that Henry can't be made as is not full Sicilian. And his name "Hill" also doesn't sound Sicilian ;-)